# How to parse JSON of a specific type with PHP Slim framework?

Tags: json, rest, slim

I have JSON string being posted by Android app to my PHP based slim framework.

Here is the JSON:

```
 ItemList=[{"Address":"addresses 263838","CreatedDate":"2016-11-11 11:53:53","DeviceID":"1","ID":0,"Latitude":24.8715396,"Locality":"locality","Longitude":67.0898003,"Name":"Item ","OfflineId":20161111115352400,"Subchannel":"Subchannel","Sublocality":"Sublocality","ToUpdate":false,"imageLocalPath":"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1478847221674.jpg"},{"Address":"address","CreatedDate":"2016-11-11 17:46:41","DeviceID":"1","ID":0,"Latitude":24.87110129,"Locality":"Locality","Longitude":67.09033959,"Name":"Item 23","OfflineId":20161111174637550,"Subchannel":"Subchannel","Sublocality":"Sublocality","ToUpdate":false,"imageLocalPath":"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1478868360328.jpg"},{"Address":"Address 648483","CreatedDate":"2016-11-12 09:43:54","DeviceID":"1","ID":0,"Latitude":24.87952002,"Locality":"Locality","Longitude":67.09332882,"Name":"Item 25","OfflineId":20161112094353314,"Subchannel":"Subchannel","Sublocality":"Sublocality","ToUpdate":false,"imageLocalPath":"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1478925794392.jpg","imageName":"1478925794392.jpg"}]
```

Slim Framework (PHP) code

```
$app->post('/itemlist', function ($request, $response) {


$input          =   $request->getParsedBody();


foreach($input as $item)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO jsondump (jsondata) VALUES (:jsondump)";

    $resQur = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $resQur->bindParam("jsondump", $item);    

    $resQur->execute();       
}

return $this->response->withJson($input);
```

});

Problem/Challenge:
The JSON list of objects should be broken into JSON objects. Currently I am dumping the JSON into the database directly to see the results. It is always dumping the whole JSON string (containing the whole list).

Comment: use `json_decode` and then loop through it.

Comment: Then how to loop. I am finding difficulty in using foreach. Not getting the expected result.

Comment: You should loop through it using foreach and then use the particular key to get the data for that key. Please provide the code that you have done and where you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the `content-type` is set to `application/json` when the data is posted, then the `$input` will be decoded automatically.

Consider this test route callable:

```
$app->post("/", function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $input = $request->getParsedBody();
    if ($input === null) {
        echo "FAILED to decode JSON\n";
        echo json_last_error_msg();
        exit;
    }

    var_dump($input);
});
```

Test:

```
$ curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
http://localhost:8888 \
-d '[{"Address":"addresses 263838","CreatedDate":"2016-11-11 11:53:53","DeviceID":"1","ID":0,"Latitude":24.8715396,"Locality":"locality","Longitude":67.0898003,"Name":"Item ","OfflineId":20161111115352400,"Subchannel":"Subchannel","Sublocality":"Sublocality","ToUpdate":false,"imageLocalPath":"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1478847221674.jpg"},{"Address":"address","CreatedDate":"2016-11-11 17:46:41","DeviceID":"1","ID":0,"Latitude":24.87110129,"Locality":"Locality","Longitude":67.09033959,"Name":"Item 23","OfflineId":20161111174637550,"Subchannel":"Subchannel","Sublocality":"Sublocality","ToUpdate":false,"imageLocalPath":"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1478868360328.jpg"},{"Address":"Address 648483","CreatedDate":"2016-11-12 09:43:54","DeviceID":"1","ID":0,"Latitude":24.87952002,"Locality":"Locality","Longitude":67.09332882,"Name":"Item 25","OfflineId":20161112094353314,"Subchannel":"Subchannel","Sublocality":"Sublocality","ToUpdate":false,"imageLocalPath":"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1478925794392.jpg","imageName":"1478925794392.jpg"}]'
```

Gives:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.12
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(13) {
    'Address' =>
    string(16) "addresses 263838"
    'CreatedDate' =>
    string(19) "2016-11-11 11:53:53"
    'DeviceID' =>
    string(1) "1"
    'ID' =>
    int(0)
    'Latitude' =>
    double(24.8715396)
    'Locality' =>
    string(8) "locality"
    'Longitude' =>
    double(67.0898003)
    'Name' =>
    string(5) "Item "
    'OfflineId' =>
    int(20161111115352400)
    'Subchannel' =>
    string(10) "Subchannel"
    'Sublocality' =>
    string(11) "Sublocality"
    'ToUpdate' =>
    bool(false)
    'imageLocalPath' =>
    string(46) "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1478847221674.jpg"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(13) {
    'Address' =>
    string(7) "address"
    'CreatedDate' =>
    string(19) "2016-11-11 17:46:41"
    'DeviceID' =>
    string(1) "1"
    'ID' =>
    int(0)
    'Latitude' =>
    double(24.87110129)
    'Locality' =>
    string(8) "Locality"
    'Longitude' =>
    double(67.09033959)
    'Name' =>
    string(7) "Item 23"
    'OfflineId' =>
    int(20161111174637550)
    'Subchannel' =>
    string(10) "Subchannel"
    'Sublocality' =>
    string(11) "Sublocality"
    'ToUpdate' =>
    bool(false)
    'imageLocalPath' =>
    string(46) "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1478868360328.jpg"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(14) {
    'Address' =>
    string(14) "Address 648483"
    'CreatedDate' =>
    string(19) "2016-11-12 09:43:54"
    'DeviceID' =>
    string(1) "1"
    'ID' =>
    int(0)
    'Latitude' =>
    double(24.87952002)
    'Locality' =>
    string(8) "Locality"
    'Longitude' =>
    double(67.09332882)
    'Name' =>
    string(7) "Item 25"
    'OfflineId' =>
    int(20161112094353314)
    'Subchannel' =>
    string(10) "Subchannel"
    'Sublocality' =>
    string(11) "Sublocality"
    'ToUpdate' =>
    bool(false)
    'imageLocalPath' =>
    string(46) "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1478925794392.jpg"
    'imageName' =>
    string(17) "1478925794392.jpg"
  }
}
```

i.e an array with three arrays within it.

Comment: Thank you @Rob Allen for the help. Yes I got it working. I will keep your advice in mind in future. Thanks for the great explanation.